# How to exclude a health check resource from Datadog metric alert monitor query?

Tags: terraform, datadog

We are setting up a metric alert monitor and other monitors using Terraforms. The query looks like this:

```
 query = "max(last_10m):p95:trace.netty.request{env:${var.env},service:${local.service_name}} >= 4"
```

We would like to exclude health checks from this particular metric only, e.g. `GET /healthcheck`

How can this be achieved? Are there some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources like the health check have a `resource_name` tag. This tag can be used to exclude them, e.g. `!resource_name:get_/health`

Here is an example of a query excluding the health check resources:

```
 query = "max(last_10m):p95:trace.netty.request{env:${var.env},service:${local.service_name},!resource_name:get_/health} >= 4"
```

Visit DataDog [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/advanced-filtering/) for more information.